# Software application that packages DOS application for Windows?

Tags: windows, virtualization, package-manager, dos

I'm looking for an application that packages a DOS application so that it will run on Windows.

Essentially I'm looking for DOSbox, but in a way that is transparent to the user. i.e., when someone clicks on the application it launches and runs the application instead of dropping them to the command-line, requiring them to mount drives, etc.

Comment: Found [a list of "DOSBox frontends"](http://www.dosbox.com/wiki/DOSBoxFrontends) and [a similar question](https://www.quora.com/Is-there-a-way-to-package-a-game-inside-of-DOSBox), but none of them seem to have answers exactly like you need as far as I looked, unfortunately :/

Comment: Why should the .bat file doing necessary preparation be a bad solution?